# Background Subtraction for Static Images

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction

I have a background image and another image with an object added. I am searching for methods to extract this object from the background by subtracting background. I am able to find only background subtraction method for videos, but not two static images. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Rather difficult without any representative images...

Comment: in your case, there is no difference between two static image and two video frames. So just take an appropriate background subtraction method used in video processing.